# Error when starting Remote Admin Manager for IIS7 1.0

Tags: iis-7, windows-xp, iis-7.5, iis-express

I have a problem that I could do with your help with.
I've installed WebMatrix, IIS 7.5 Express from the Web Platform Installer 3.0.
I did have IIS 5 installed on the machine as well but I have removed that and installed Remote Admin Manager for IIS7 1.0.  I downloaded it from the following location http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=32C54C37-7530-4FC0-BD20-177A3E5330B7#Instructions

When I try to connect to localhost through the admin manager I get the following error message:

---

### Failed to connect

There was an error when trying to connect. Do you want to retype your credentials and try again?

Details:

### Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

### Yes   No

I've had a look about and some posts were saying remove the other IIS which is what I did.  I have got the right versions of the .NET framework installed from what I can see (they are 2 to 4).  I am running this on Windows XP SP3.

How do I cure this?  I think it will be something simple but I'm not sure what it is.
It mentions something about retyping the credentials but I am not sure what they are.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You attempted a very logical thing. One would expect the remote admin manager to work against the IIS Express. But it is not the case. As of today, IIS Express unfortunately doesn't support IIS Manager experience.